# 64Gb RAM in a mid-2010 12-core MacPro

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I am interested in installing 64Gb RAM in a mid-2010 12-core MacPro. Crucial does not offer any 64Gb kits, but they do offer a 2x8Gb kit:

http://www.crucial.com/eu/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=60826169A5CA7304

Is it technically possible to install four of these kits in a MacPro? Or is there a reason that they don't sell a 64Gb kit? The specs of the RAM are 'DDR3 PC3-10600 • CL=9 • Dual Ranked • Registered • ECC • DDR3-1333 • 1.5V • 1024Meg x 72'

Comment: Well, the page says that it has 8x RAM slots, so you should be able to populate each slot with an 8GB stick, taking you up to 64GB. It's not cheap though...ouch.

Comment: **"Or is there a reason that they don't sell a 64Gb kit?"** - There isn't a huge demand for it would be my guess.

Comment: Gotta love Apple - $400US for something that costs <$250 in the PC world, and last I heard the _only_ difference in the product at all is the byte order (endian-ness)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - When you compare the pricing for the "Apple-specific" version of the RAM module to the non-specific "value RAM"-style equivalents from a manufacturer like Kingston memory, the pricing is <$20 more per stick for the "Apple" sticks.  This is the same deal as when buying other OEM-specific RAM modules (like Dell or HP).  The difference is the modules that are marked specifically have had their design specifically tested and blessed by the OEMs.  This costs the RAM manufacturers extra to do, so they pass it on.

Comment: @techie this is hardly "value ram": http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231489

Comment: @techie though to be fair I also really need to compare UK price to UK price, since VAT and other factors can influence this. In fact, checking Amazon UK it seems that 8GB sticks are harder to come by over there at all; most 16GB kits I saw were 4x4. Still, I was able to find a PC part for €100 less.

Comment: Ah, looking at the crucial part again, it's _registered_ (ECC) ram. That hardly matters for desktops, but it does explain (part) of the price difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Pro#Specifications):

> Expandable to 32 GB on Quad-core models, and 64 GB in 8- and 12-core
>   models (although expandable to 96GB using 3rd party 6x16GB DIMMS)

Comment: Interesting - why not expandable to 8x16Gb with 3rd party DIMMS since there are 8 slots? This is the reason I wanted to check if I can actually fill all 8 slots with 8Gb DIMMS.

Comment: @astrofrog - Probably the board doesn't support it.  (I have no idea what the innards of these things are - maybe the chipset doesn't, either.  That's doubtful, though.)

Comment: BIOS/chipset has to support it as well, you can't go back to an older PC motherboad that has four slots, stick 16GB in and work with 64GB of RAM either.

Comment: @kbyrd - but so the MacPro can definitely take 8x8Gb?

Comment: @astrofrog: Yes, that's how I read that bit from Wikipedia.